# Upload images to heroku through delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm trying to upload images to s3 bucket from Heroku using delayed job.

But it seems heroku delayed job isn't able to get the tmp image path.
Please let me know what I'm doing wrong or a better approach.

Here is my code of controller:

```
  if @post.save
    unless @post.post_type == 0
      image_a = image_b = ''
      if item_image_params['0'][:item_type] == "A"
        image_a = item_image_params['0'][:image]
        image_b = item_image_params['1'][:image]
      else
        image_a = item_image_params['1'][:image]
        image_b = item_image_params['0'][:image]
      end
      @post.delay.save_image(image_a.path, image_b.path)
    end
  end
```

My model code:

```
  def save_image(image_a, image_b)
    items.each do |item|
      if item.item_type == "A"
        item.build_item_image.image = File.open(image_a)
      else
        item.build_item_image.image = File.open(image_b)
      end
    end
    if self.save
      File.delete(image_a) if File.exist?(image_a)
      File.delete(image_b) if File.exist?(image_b)
    end
  end
```

I'm getting this error in delayed:

```
:save_image args: - /tmp/RackMultipart20150715-3-1qoy83r.jpeg - /tmp/RackMultipart20150715-3-if712h.jpeg 
 last_error:
  "No such file or directory - /tmp/RackMultipart20150715-3-if712h.jpeg\n/app/app/models/post.rb:35:in
```

On line no 35 the code is:

```
 item.build_item_image.image = File.open(image_b)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku dynos cannot access each other's local file systems.  If I'm understanding correctly, you have a web dyno writing to its local file system (/tmp) and then are trying to read it from a different (worker) dyno.

You are far better off having the upload go straight to S3.  I have used [carrierwave_direct](https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct) with good success or you can use something else or roll your own.

Uploading directly to S3 also has the advantage of not tying up your web dynos while uploads are in progress as well bypassing their timeouts.  If uploads go straight to heroku and take longer than the web dyno's timeout (because the file is large or the user's connection is slow) then the upload will simply fail.

I see you have tagged this question with `paperclip`.  You may find [this article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3) from Heroku to be useful, though it looks like it is not using the preferred approach of uploading directly to s3.  [This blog post](http://blog.littleblimp.com/post/53942611764/direct-uploads-to-s3-with-rails-paperclip-and) has some sample code for uploading directly to s3 with paperclip.

Comment: What if I move that tmp file to our app public directory folder. Is it feasible? I mean will it save some user time if I using the delayed?

Comment: That still has the same problem of using dyno local storage.  That local storage is isolated from other dynos and ephemeral.  If you moved the files to the public directory they still would only be usable by the dyno that received them and only for the life of that dyno.  They would be gone when you deploy a new version, restart, etc.